# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v2.train' has no attribute 'string_input_producer'

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I tried to run the https://github.com/4Catalyzer/cyclegan.git
I have error like

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v2.train' has no attribute 'string_input_producer'

I use python 3.8.5 and tensorflow 2.4.1

Answer (score 0):

`tf.compat.v1.train.string_input_producer` is deprecated in. It will be removed in a future version. Instructions for updating: Queue-based input pipelines have been replaced by `tf.data`.

Use `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(string_tensor)`.

`shuffle(tf.shape(input_tensor, out_type=tf.int64)[0]).repeat(num_epochs)`. If shuffle=False, omit the .shuffle(...)